# obtener multiples valores con attr en un select

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Estoy teniendo una lista desplegable de selección múltiple de la siguiente manera, en ella añadi el atributo "tiempo".

```
<select>
<optgroup label="Tercera generacion">
  <option value="A8" tiempo="5">Algol 8</option>
  <option value="PL" tiempo="10">PL/I</option>
  <option value="PC" tiempo="15">Pascal</option>
 <option Value="MD" tiempo="20">Modula</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

Por ejemplo, si selecciono la opcion "Pascal" me traerá el valor del atributo "tiempo" que seria 15, pero si selecciono ademas de esta otras, también debería de obtenerlas.

El detalle es que cuando utilizo el siguiente codigo, solo me trae lo del primer valor seleccionado.

```
$("#listgen option:selected").attr("tiempo")
```

y nada mas, ¿como obtengo el resto de los valores?, ya que mi objetivo era sumarlos e imprimir el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si querés seleccionar más de un resultado, tu select debería ser múltiple:
`<select multiple="multiple">`.

El resultado de todos los seleccionados los vas a tener en el valor del combo. Ponele que tu select tenga de id listgen, entonces:

`$("#listgen").val()` --> esto te devuelve un array con los seleccionados.
Para sumarlos, podés recorrerlos con un reduce y hacer la suma.

```
var arr = $("#listgen").val();
var suma = arr.reduce((total, actual) => total + actual);
```